# Extract connections in airflow and use in boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, boto3, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I am. trying to extract connections from airflow as

```
key,pass = BaseHook.get_connection('aws_default') 
print(conn.get_extra())
```

and use it in my boto3 connection as:

```
account_id = boto3.client('sts',aws_access_key_id=key,
aws_secret_access_key=pass).get_caller_identity().get('Account').
```

I am getting this error, how to resolve this?

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: connection
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Are you using Secrets Manager for storing connections? Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/connections-secrets-manager.html

Comment: How are you storing the key and secret in the Airflow UI?